# PHP Curl certificate problems, fix it once and for all

Tags: php, curl

This is not a duplicate, I've read hundreds of posts and documentation about this, and I still can't get cURL to work on my local machine, despite having tested nearly all test cases.

**PHP Info**

Version: 5.5.36

`php.ini`: `/etc/php.ini`

SSL: Yes

SSL Version: SecureTransport

Certificate downloaded here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

**php.ini cURL cainfo setting**

```
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo=/Users/me/cacert.pem
```

**PHP Script** *(The request itself works in Postman)*

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
// headers include json content type ang GCM authorization key
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// json is correct, works via postman with same params
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/Users/me/cacert.pem'); // it exists
```

**Test cases description and errors**

With parameters above

> SSL: certificate verification failed (result: 5)

When setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false` and removing `CURLOPT_CAINFO`

> SSL: CA certificate set, but certificate verification is disabled

When removing only `CURLOPT_CAINFO`, keeping `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `true`

> SSL: certificate verification failed (result: 5)

I have read about [cURL issues on Yosemite](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/819) (I'm on OS ElCapitain). If I do `curl --cacert /Users/me/cacert.pem https://google.com`, from the command line I also get `curl: (51) SSL: certificate verification failed (result: 5)` BUT, it works with https://paypal.com

Comment: Are you running php using the command-line? Can php read `/Users/me/cacert.pem`?

Comment: I've made both tests from the command line and apache server. A different php ini file is used but both curl certificate path info are set. I think php can read it (from a script i ran `is_file('/Users/me/cacert.pem')` which returns `true`

Comment: If you are trying to send a JSON string to Google GCM with PHP, you do not need to use curl at all. If you like I can post an example without curl.

Comment: I'd be interested. But the problem is different, i'm pretty sure its issues with latest MAC OS (Yosemite / El Capitain), its hinders any other curl feature you use on your projects... A real pain in the a*** !

Comment: can you show the output of `curl -v  --cacert /Users/me/cacert.pem https://google.com`

Comment: * Rebuilt URL to: https://google.com/
*   Trying 216.58.211.78...
* Connected to google.com (216.58.211.78) port 443 (#0)
* SSL: certificate verification failed (result: 5)
* Closing connection 0
curl: (51) SSL: certificate verification failed (result: 5)

Comment: When I do it, the output begins `* Rebuilt URL to: https://google.com/
*   Trying 212.113.7.172...
* Connected to google.com (212.113.7.172) port 443 (#0)
* found 157 certificates in cacert.pem
`

Comment: Your output suggests that it never even looks for certificates in your cacert location. Does the `--capath` option do anything? You might be able to use `--capath /Users/me/`

Comment: No my output suggests that the certificate IS set, but failed to validate.

Comment: curl -v --capath /Users/romain/ https://google.com
curl: (4) A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl due to a build-time decision.

Comment: The part my output has that yours doesn't have is `found 157 certificates in cacert.pem`. I'm not sure why your output doesn't have that. I can't really do any more because I have a different `curl` from you. But I would aim the debugging at how it deals with the cacert argument, and the difference between the success case(s) and the fail case(s).